# Actionscript 3.0 Creating bitmapData from Loaded URL

Tags: image, actionscript-3, bitmapdata, image-loading

I want to load an image and then use its bitmapData. The program worked when I ran it from flash, but not when I uploaded it online. There seem to be a bunch of weird problems. The
`addChild(myLoader)` works online but `addChild(loadedPic)` does not, and the myLoader doesn't seem to have bitmapData I can access.
For some reason the `urlInput.text = "Done."` will work online but not the `urlInput.text = ...` that I added to see what's going on. When I run this on my computer I get the urlInput saying "[object Bitmap] hi" like it should, but online it just says "Loading..." still

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();

submitButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonRelease);
function buttonRelease(event:MouseEvent){
    var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlInput.text);
    urlInput.text = "Loading...";
    myLoader.load(fileRequest);
}

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
function onComplete(e:Event){
    urlInput.text = "Done.";
    //addChild(myLoader);

    //var loadedBitmap = new BitmapData(myLoader.width, myLoader.height);
    //loadedBitmap.draw(myLoader);
    //var loadedPic = e.target.content;
    //loadedPic.width = 300;
    //loadedPic.height = 300;
    //addChild(loadedPic);
    urlInput.text = e.target.content.toString() + " hi";
    //usedPic = loadedPic;
}
```

Comment: where are you loading the bitmap from? what is the path, is it relative or absolute, and is it on the same domain as your swf?

Comment: Be sure you're using the flash debug player when you're checking it online, it sounds to me lie you may be getting a security violation but not seeing the error, verify you are running the flash player debug version here (near bottom of the page): http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html note that chrome normally maintains it's flash player internally special steps are needed to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading an image and you want to access it's data (to do the `draw()` call), then you'll need to load it with a `LoaderContext` object with the `checkPolicyFile` bool set to true. The reason it works on local is that everything is implicitly trusted on local so you don't really run into security problems

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6